# Does cobertura support java 8 ?Because i want to use java8 labmda expression and it is giving me an error

Tags: spring-boot, maven-2, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin, maven-cobertura-plugin

I am new Cobertura I have written Test case and I use Lambda expression in coding  and it is giving me an error how to solve this issue.

I search on google and came to know that Jacoco support Java8.

But how to insert jacoco plugin as Cobertura  plugin i am not getting.

Cobertura   plugin in my spring boot project pom.xml is like below:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- <check> <branchRate>85</branchRate> <lineRate>85</lineRate> <haltOnFailure>true</haltOnFailure> 
                        <totalBranchRate>85</totalBranchRate> <totalLineRate>85</totalLineRate> <packageLineRate>85</packageLineRate> 
                        <packageBranchRate>85</packageBranchRate> </check> -->
                    <formats>
                        <format>xml</format>
                    </formats>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>cobertura</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Cobertura - JaCoCo provides Maven plugin. Its description as well as examples can be found in [JaCoCo documentation](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html). As one of examples

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
      <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.8.4</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            <goal>report</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
```